# Timer triggered in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to trigger a countdown timer to start running when the value of an IF function cell changes. I'm thinking something along the lines of IF(A1<>"",1,"") where the countdown would trigger when A1 = 1.

Alongside that the ability to reset that countdown timer cell on the condition of another cell changing value, I was thinking the same type of IF function.

I've seen some places that say the best way to do this is to write some code onto the sheet itself rather than a Macro on a Module to be called, but I'm not sure of the best way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The [`Worksheet_Calculate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event, yes.

Comment: If this is related to your previous question, can you provide the `Worksheet_Calculate` code you used?

Comment: Yes the worksheet is set as a calculate event, it isn't linked to the other question but I have uploaded the old code version on that question to provide more detail.

Comment: I don't see any `Worksheet_Calculate` code snippet in your old question?

Comment: sorry what I meant was the old question was a macro that I had copied from a module so was not itself embedded within a worksheet, only called by a worksheet that was itself set as Worksheet_Calculate